# How to check if the Android device is running an Intel processor?

Tags: android

Is there any code in the Android SDK that lets me check if the device is running on an Intel processor?

thanks.

Comment: try this http://www.roman10.net/how-to-get-cpu-information-on-android/

Comment: see this tut maybe helpful http://android-er.blogspot.in/2009/09/read-android-cpu-info.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be using `Build.CPU_ABI` and `Build.CPU_ABI2` to somehow detect the running processor. Just take a look at the [`Build`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) class which gives:

> Information about the current build, extracted from system properties.

Comment: The Intel emulator returns 'x86' in Build.CPU_ABI . Thanks.

Comment: This method is somewhat unreliable. Some Intel-based devices (such as the Asus Fonepad 7) will report CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a and CPU_ABI2=armeabi, despite the device having an Intel-processor.

Comment: Now `Build` docs says: CPU_ABI  This field was deprecated in API level 21. Use SUPPORTED_ABIS instead.

Answer (score 1):

Not to my knowledge, but the only time when you really need to know the ISA of the processor is when you need to run native code.
So one way is to simply add a method in your native library that returns different value for different ISA (MIPS, ARM, x86). And you just need one JNI call to get the answer you wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use it as a hack, but maybe you can find it useful. The idea is to use the cat to parse /proc/cpuinfo, and the look for GenuineIntel on it. I am using it on one app.

As I said, seems a hack, maybe a more experienced Android developer can propose a better solution.

```
private boolean isAnIntel() {
   String[] args = {"/system/bin/cat", "/proc/cpuinfo"};
   cmd = new ProcessBuilder(args);

   Process process = cmd.start();
   InputStream in = process.getInputStream();
   byte[] re = new byte[1024];
   while(in.read(re) != -1){
    result = result + new String(re);
   }
   in.close();
   return result.indexOf("GenuineIntel") > 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: Many Intel devices seem to provide you with a fake cpuinfo when read through the app :( See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041547/how-can-i-detect-when-android-x86-is-emulating-arm

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget android is LINUX
All CPU information are on the file "/proc/cpuinfo"
If processor is intel then value of vendor_id in that file will be GenuineIntel. (vendor_id : GenuineIntel)

Answer (score 0):

On Intel blog there is article https://software.intel.com/en-us/blogs/2014/12/16/how-to-identify-the-image-is-32-bit-or-64-bit-user-space they advice to use `ro.product.cpu.abi` property or again `Build` that has changed API since Android 5.0

```
CPU_ABI
CPU_ABI2
SUPPORTED_32_BIT_ABIS
SUPPORTED_64_BIT_ABIS
SUPPORTED_ABIS
```