# How can I detect when Android x86 is emulating ARM?

Tags: android-ndk, x86, arm

I have a JNI library that runs well on most Android devices - ARMv5, ARMv7, and x86.

I'm using NEON instructions on ARMv7, but instead of cluttering the code with conditional/duplicated source, I want to detect a non-NEON ARMv7 in Java at library load time, and load the v5 library instead: slow CPU is slow.

I found a post suggesting that I look for the 'neon' feature in /proc/cpuinfo, so I'm parsing that, and loading libthing.so usually, or libthing-v5.so if the device claims to be an ARMv7 without NEON. This works nicely on ARM.

Unfortunately not only does x86 emulate an ARM /proc/cpuinfo(!), if it decides it doesn't understand NEON then it also digs out the libthing-v5.so from the armeabiv7a directory, and uses it because there isn't one in the x86 directory.

My current workaround is just to copy the x86 library to both libthing.so and libthing-v5.so so if x86 is pretending to be a NEON-free ARMv7 chip, it'll get the x86 library anyway.

Aside from cooking up a tiny standalone architecture-detecting library of my own based on Yeppp or Android's own cpufeatures, is there a way to determine the genuine local architecture from Java?

---

@ph0b: Herewith the output of the Razr i, showing that the emulator has decided that the application has been installed as an 'ABI2 58', and that it needs to fake out /proc/cpuinfo.

Given that both shared libraries are available from x86 as well as the armeabi* directories, I don't understand why the device has decided to be an ARM. I might ask my contact at Intel about this.

```
06-05 10:58:41.360 17807 18053 D dalvikvm: Trying to load lib /data/data/com.company.android/lib/libmp.so 0x42409cb0
06-05 10:58:41.360 17807 18053 D dalvikvm: Added shared lib /data/data/com.company.android/lib/libmp.so 0x42409cb0
06-05 10:58:41.370 17807 18053 D dalvikvm: No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/data/com.company.android/lib/libmp.so 0x42409cb0, skipping init
06-05 10:58:41.420 17807 18053 D         : Searching package installed with ABI2 with Uid: 10109 
06-05 10:58:41.420 17807 18053 D         : Apps with ABI2 58 accessing /proc/cpuinfo 
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: #Here's most of /proc/cpuinfo
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: #Thu Jun 05 10:58:41 GMT+01:00 2014
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: Serial=0000000000000001
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: Revision=0001
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: CPU=revision\t\: 1
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: BogoMIPS=1500
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: Hardware=placeholder
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: Features=vfp swp half thumb fastmult edsp vfpv3 
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I System.out: Processor=ARMv7 processor rev 1 (v7l)
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 I NativeWahooLibrary: Detected ARMv7 processor rev 1 (v7l) (=ARMv7, true) with (neon@-1) vfp swp half thumb fastmult edsp vfpv3 
06-05 10:58:41.430 17807 18053 D dalvikvm: Trying to load non-neon lib /data/data/com.company.android/lib/libwahoo-v5.so 0x42409cb0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt the x86 emulates an ARM /proc/cpuinfo !?

Anyway, in order to detect the local architecture from Java, you can rely on `Build.CPU_ABI` and `Build.CPU_ABI2`: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#CPU_ABI, and then continue parsing /proc/cpuinfo to look for neon only if CPU_ABI and CPU_ABI2 are arm*/armeabi-v7a

Comment: See above for bizarre output from Razri which shows an ARM /proc/cpuinfo. It emits an x86 /proc/cpuinfo for my test app. Other than that, CPU_ABI=x86 and CPU_ABI2=armeabi-v7a on both Intel devices I have handy; my real ARM devices have CPU_ABI=armeabi-v7a and CPU_ABI2=armeabi, except for one that unexpectedly turned out to be Intel too(!).

Comment: @ph0b seems like the app that contain x86 and arm-v7 got detected as "armeabi-v7a" (eg: Asus Zenfone device) in `Build.CPU_ABI` and `Build.CPU_ABI2`, if we try compile an app to output `Build.CPU_ABI*` without NDK, it will show the correct result, which is `x86` and `armeabi-v7a` , any idea for this?

Comment: if the app contains x86 libs that are getting installed (or no libs at all) on a x86 device, the `Build.CPU_ABI` should return x86, else something is wrong with the build that is on the device. Sometime on the Zenfone, the libs that are actually installed are the arm ones because it thinks that some x86 libs are missing so it falls back to arm libs. You can easily determine this using my application: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xh.nativelibsmonitor.app

Answer (score 2):

You cannot rely on proc/cpuinfo, getProperty("os.arch") or Build.CPU_ABI(2). They are all fake if emulation is active. The way I do the detection is I parse the /proc/cpuinfo looking for a word "placeholder". It's in "Hardware:" line. Normally there's a real company name like "Samsung" for Samsung Galaxy, but in case of ARM emulation on x86 I see there is just "placeholder" in hardware line in /proc/cpuinfo. I haven't tested it on lot of device models, so cannot say how reliable this way is.

Answer (score 2):

You can also retrieve the `e_machine` value defined in ELF file header, for example the file `libc.so`, to detect which architecture is specified.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header

Code snippet:

```
File libc = new File(Environment.getRootDirectory(), "lib/libc.so"); // or 'lib64' if 64 bit
// assert libc file exsits
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile(libc, "r");
file.seek(0x12); // 'e_machine' offset
byte[] buf = new byte[2]; // 2 bytes size
file.readFully(buf);
int em = (buf[0] & 0xff) | ((buf[1] & 0xff) << 8);
file.close();
if(em == 0x03 || em == 0x3E) {
    // x86!
}
```

When `Build.CPU_ABI` indicates you are running on ARM, but conflicts with the x86 `em`, it is emulating!

Answer (score 0):

As horrible as this sounds if you have a different list of native libs for ARM and x86 then devices like the will automatically switch to running the application under the ARM emulator.

https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/android-applications-on-intel-architecture/topic/518471