# Atom/x86 versus ARM CPU code execution on Android devices

Tags: android, android-ndk, x86, arm, intel

Code already debugged on ARM tablets, I used an Android tablet with Intel Atom CPU to test the native x86 code of my app (.so generated by NDK)...

As expected,
1) CPU-Z utility gives "Architecture x86" and "CPU Intel Atom Z3735G"
2) "adb shell cat /proc/cpuinfo" gives "model name : Intel(R) Atom(TM) CPU  Z3735G @ 1.33GHz"

When the app is launched,
as unexpected,
1) Log.d (TAG, "CPU:"+ android.os.Build.CPU_ABI) gives: "CPU:armeabi-v7a"
2) Some native .so libraries of my app exist only in ARM code and they work here properly.

I doubt the x86 .so lib is used even if available

The behavior is exactly the same as CPU ARM.
Do you have an explanation?
Is the code translated to x86? If the code is converted, it very well works!

Comment: I wonder if compiler is concating strings in "Log.d (TAG, "CPU:"+ android.os.Build.CPU_ABI)" at compile time, so you see what you see.

Answer (score 2):

x86 based Android devices including a ARM emulation layer which I guess is used while executing your application. When the emulation is used is not always intuitive.

You should check if you have the **same number** of files in libs/x86 and libs/armeabi and libs/armeabi-v7a inside the apk file. So if you have two native libs for arm you should also have two native libs for x86.

If the number matches and it still does not work check if the **names** of the native libraries are the same for ARM and x86.

Comment: you are right. Libs types seem to be evaluated to choose the ABI, x86 or armeabi-v7a. I remarked the behavior described here in the answer: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041547/how-can-i-detect-when-android-x86-is-emulating-arm?rq=1)
 
"if the app contains x86 libs that are getting installed (or no libs at all) on a x86 device, the Build.CPU_ABI should return x86, else something is wrong with the build that is on the device. [..], the libs that are actually installed are the arm ones because it thinks that some x86 libs are missing so it falls back to arm libs"

Comment: Have you checked the naming and quantity of the libs for the different ABIs? Are they the same?

Comment: I have a lot of only arm libs (openCV). The tablet says "I am armv7". if I remove these libs. (one multi-cpu arm-armv7-x86-mips lib stays) the tablet says "I am x86". (=  I will not meet arm code on my way...)

Comment: This principle seems good. But it is better to understand it. Drawback: The compilations on several CPU must be separately tested. So that arm emulation is more simple... arm emulation seems fast and not so bad.